# Convert Last N characters to dot if length of the terminal is less than width of terminal using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to limit the output of some command till the end of the terminal width. If it is exceeding the terminal size then replace the exceeding characters plus few more to dots.

I am not able to pin put solution, just been around from long time. Here is an example:

```
echo $x
this is a sample string and this does not mean anything this is to feed length

echo $x |awk '{print length($0)}' #Here terminal size is greater then line's length. 
78
```

Terminal size:

```
tput cols
168
```

However, If I have a smaller window:

```
tput cols
74
```

Then the content of `$x` is going to spread into two lines, I want the excess characters to be weed out.

So If the terminal size is 74 then `$x` should print as :

```
echo $x
this is a sample string and this does not mean anything this is to feed ..
```

HEre is what I was thinking to implement, but I am lost now.

```
echo $x |awk --posix  -v c=$(tput cols) '{l=length($0);if(l>c) {difference=l-c ;gsub(/.\{difference\}$/,"",$0);print $0}else print  $0}'
this is a sample string and this does not mean anything this is to feed length
```

Comment: Never use the letter `l` as a variable name as it looks FAR too much like the number `1` and so obfuscates your code. Also, when you have code like `if(x) {do Y; do Z} else do Z` then refactor it to `if(x) do Y; do Z` so you're not duplicating the common code. In your code that'd be the `print $0`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this?

```
  ... | awk -v t=$(tput cols) '{if(length($0)>t) print substr($0,1,t-4) "...";
                                else print}'
```

Comment: exactly like this. Thanks...!

Comment: one question ...Can you pls point out what is wrong in my command ? seems fine to me... ?

Comment: @PS wrt `/.\{difference\}$/` in your code, your 2 real semantic errors are: 1) this is awk, not sed, so EREs are enabled by default and as such you do not escape ERE metacharacters to enable them as they already ARE enabled and escaping them disables them - use `{...}`, not `\{...\}`. 2) `/.../` is a regexp constant. You cannot use variables like `difference` within a constant regexp, you need a dynamic regexp formed by string concatenation `".{"difference"}"`. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps.

Answer (score 1):

error explain in the code

```
echo $x \
| awk --posix  -v c=$(tput cols) '
    {
    l = length($0)
    if( l > c ) { 
       # difference = l - c 

       # variable difference is not interpretated in regex format
       # $0 is the default variable of (g)sub
       # gsub(/.\{difference\}$/,"",$0)
       # gsub( ".{" difference "}$","", $0)
       sub( ".{" ( l - c + 3 ) "}$","...")

       # print $0
       }
    # else print  $0
    }

    #print
    7
    '
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use karakfa's idea in a simple assignment as well:

```
... | awk -v c=$(tput cols) '$0 = length > c ? substr($0,1,c-4) : $0'
```

Comment: that's not simple, it just looks like it is. In fact it's causing the result of the assignment to be evaluated as a condition which is then used to determine if the current record should be printed or not. If the input line was empty or zero or anything that evaluated to zero, it wouldn't get printed which I suspect is undesirable. Only use an assignment as a condition if you have a specific behavior you want as a result of the condition being evaluated and fully understand the side-effects. Oh, and that might cause a syntax error on some awks due to the unparenthesized ternary expression.